# How to tell where an autolaunched flow is called from?

Tags: apex, unit-test, visual-workflow

I'm in the process of transitioning all flows/workflows/processes into Apex code for easier debugging and error fixing, and am trying to figure out where an autolaunched flow is called from. There seems to be no way to do this through the UI, which is fine, but there must be a way through the XML that is quick and easy. Otherwise I have no idea what is actually triggering this flow, and can't write tests.

Comment: use your IDE (with a project that includes all metadata types) and search for the api name of the Flow

Answer (score 1):

You can give the following query a try using Tooling API:
`SELECT MetadataComponentId, MetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentId, RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentNamespace, RefMetadataComponentType from MetadataComponentDependency WHERE MetadataComponentId = 'your_flow_id_not_the_version_id'`

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm